# Constraint issue on UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a collection view cell here where i places the labels...

[image]

However when I put a new constraint on top of my Headline label, so that it doesnt run out of the cell it appears to be [image]

Anyone knows why this is happening? My constraint constant is only 8, it shouldnt be so big

Comment: May be your label  number of line property 1.So it show in one line and other things it happen in UI of cell not adjust according our constrain when run your code it looking proper.i think it's help for you.

Comment: Did you specify to your label how many lines there should be? if it is just 1 line, it will try to shrink the text, if you put 0, it will break lines until it fills up the entire label's frame. Check in attributes inspector.

Comment: the one with headline headline headline, i have set it to line 0...unsure why when i put a constraint on top, it pushes all my words to bottom and hidden

Comment: Is this a single label or multiple labels.

Comment: there are two labels..but no matter one or two label, when i put a constraint on top, it runs out of the layout

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1 :-** 
Set top constraint to `>= 5` and below constraint to `>=5` and make your label lines to 0.

**Method 2 :-**

Set the height of the label to `>= 40` Set top and bottom constraint to `>=5`.

**Method 3 :-**

Give it COntraint Vertically in container and set top and bottom constraints to `>=5`

***Note:-*** IT is just an example values you can change values according to your need